# Retag versus edit: Which one should be used for retagging?

Tags: support, edits, retag-request, privileges

I know retagging question using   [Retag questions privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) doesn't give you any reputation and also doesn't require peer review. On the contrary, using edit for retagging with a minor change in the content of respective question gives +2 rep(unless the rep cap is reached) if it's accepted and also requires peer review which ensures correct/useful retagging. Frankly speaking, this fact encourages me using **edit** instead of **retag question privilege** which may be true for many other users, IMO.

So, which method should I use for retagging?

If I edit the question I get a peer check to make sure my re-tagging is acceptable.

I think my retagging may always not be perfect which is not checked if I use Retag privilege but, if I use edit then a safety check is ensured via peer review which encourages me to use edit.

Comment: Honestly, does the +2 mean so much to you? You get +5 for upvoted questions and +10 for upvoted answers.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn no, I think my retagging may always not be perfect which is not checked if I use Retag privilege but, if I use edit then a safety check is ensured via peer review which encourages me to use edit.

Comment: Took me a while to understand your comment.  Imran is stating that if he edits the question he gets a peer check to make sure his re-tagging is acceptable.

Comment: Why downvoted :O? Explain please.

Comment: @BoltClock You can gain 1000 rep by doing this, one retag at a time. That's worth a lot to a low rep user, no?

Comment: As @Bryan is mentioning, I think the OP is talking primarily about the fact that he gets his retag peer reviewed by using the edit function, and just mentions the +2 as a bonus encouragement to use the edit feature. I agree with him. It seems odd that there is no peer review just because you use a feature that requires more reputation. I think it's fine that we trust in high rep users, but shouldn't they at least be given the option to get it reviewed by others if they're not entirely sure of their retagging?

Comment: I thought you had to have 10k to get a retagging button, in which case you don't go through the suggested edit queue with normal edits anyway.

Comment: Retag as a separate privilege [has been removed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all you are doing is retagging, use the retag functionality.

If you are making good edits on the post itself, as well as retagging, use the edit functionality.

Do not make minor edits just to gain the +2 reputation.

Comment: +1 The last sentence serves as a stern warning.

Comment: I think my retagging may always not be perfect which is not checked if I use Retag privilege but, if I use edit then a safety check is ensured via peer review which encourages me to use edit.

Comment: Where is the retag functionality? I can't find it.

Comment: @Bill - when editing a post, you can change the tags. With enough reputation, an inline tag editor comes up.

Comment: @Oded Oh, I see the inline tag editor and change the tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I would say that if you can improve the question in any other way.  Such as making the title more descriptive, formatting the question better, etc. then edit and **include those edits** along with the new tags.  That way not only have we re-tagged the question and better organized it, we have also edited and improved the actual meat of the question.

But don't just edit for the reputation.  Edit to improve the site.

Comment: No, I think my retagging may always not be perfect which is not checked if I use Retag privilege but, if I use edit then a safety check is ensured via peer review which encourages me to use edit.