# Why do we have the "retag" privilege?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, privileges

On StackOverflow there is a privilege called "retag questions". It requires 500 rep to use, and upon using the privilege you earn the "Organizer" Badge.

But.. Why do we have this privilege? It simply adds a button to retag posts. However posts can actually be retagged through normal editing without the 500 rep.

If this means that you may retag just without going through the "peer-review" system of the site, shouldn't it say that somewhere like the "Edit Questions and Answers" privilege description does?

Comment: The retag system was implemented before peer reviewing, and yes, it does skip the review queues.

Comment: I figured that, so then shouldn't it include that to fit the style of the "Edit Questions and Answers" privilege description?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retag versus edit: Which one should be used for retagging?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132490/retag-versus-edit-which-one-should-be-used-for-retagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we still need the Retag privilege?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "[retag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions)" privilege allows the users who don't have the privilege of editing every post to edit the tags. When the privilege was introduced, the suggested edits were not yet implemented. This means that the only users who were able to edit a post were the ones having the "[edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)" privilege, except when the post was CW which would be editable from everybody who had the "[edit community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki)" privilege.

Now that suggested edits are implemented, the "retag questions" privilege allows users to change the tags used from a question without to put the edit in the suggested edits queue.

The privilege page for "retag questions" is fine as it is. It cannot say anything said from the "edit questions and answers" privilege page, as the users with just the "retag questions" privilege don't still have the privilege of editing every post; the part about when a post should be edited doesn't make sense for retagging a question.

If you are saying the "retag questions" should make clear that the retags done with the "retag" link are not going through the peer review system, then I agree with that.

Comment: I mention the edit questions and answers because it contains "That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit anything in the system without it going through the peer review system" So I thought that retag Questions should have something along the same lines

Comment: The "retag questions" privilege page could say the retags done through the "retag" link are not going to be peer reviewed. I agree.

Comment: I have edited the [retag questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) privilege page here on MSO to include, "Retags done through the `retag` menu option under the post are not added to the peer review queue." That is the privilege page pushed to other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Didn't know you could do that... but thanks (I feel like I've made a big difference on Stack Exchange now haha) any idea on when those resync with each other?

Comment: Privilege pages are wiki pages; you should see an "edit wiki" link at the bottom. (If you are not a 20K user, you can just suggest edits.) As for when the pages are synchronized, as far as I recall, that is manually done from developers.

Comment: There is no option to do this on SO even with the Edit Community Wiki privilege. If you like you can go see if you can find it/edit it

Comment: I meant here on Meta Stack Overflow. The other sites don't have links to edit the privilege pages. (I am a moderator on Drupal Answers, and I don't see links for editing privilege pages, there.)

Comment: Okay, I guess someone way up there will have to do an edit. Until then all we can do it wait