# Can we route retags by edit through retag interface?

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, suggested-edits

When you have at least 500 reputation, and you go to retag a question, it goes through a separate channel, than the suggested edits do. However if you have 500 reputation, and you attempt to suggest an edit, that just adds tags, it will give you this error:

[image: retag error]

Is there a specific reason why this returns an error, as opposed to routing through the retag interface?

Comment: Why not edit it, making it a feature request instead of a question?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx It is a feature request.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132490

Comment: @ChrisF I believe that is actually what caused this...

Comment: This was [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit), after which retag as a separate privilege [was removed entirely.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you (hence my +1 on your question), but I'll share my thoughts on why it's a problematic implementation.

You have the ability to edit tags (i.e. the retag privilege), but you do *not* yet have the ability to edit the question body or title (i.e. the edit privilege).

Because of that, the system cannot place the two in the same page, because it won't be able to differentiate between the two.

So instead, you have a different channel, and the system will not allow you to use the normal channel anymore.

Once you get the edit posts privilege, that restriction will be lifted.